# Expected value of socks that are yet to be pulled

Tags: probability

- We have a box with $N$ pairs of socks. We can't look into this box.
- Someone came along, and randomly removed a value $M$ of socks in the range $[0, 2N]$. $M$ is selected uniformly at random, with every choice of M socks being equally probable.
- We don't know *how many* socks they removed, but we *do know* how many matching pairs were taken out, denoted by $K$.
- So the question is, given $N$ and $K$, what is the expected number of socks that are still in the box?

---

As part of the problem, we are given some example values:

$E(N=1, K=0) = 1.5$.

$E(N=2, K=0) = 3.125$

$E(N=2, K=1) = 1.25$

---

The first one makes sense to me. If no pairs are complete, that means there are two cases either 1 or 0 socks were taken (1 or 2 socks remain in the box). So the expected value is $E = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2} + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} $. But I haven't figured out how the other cases can be right, or how something like this could even be generalized to any value of N or K. I can imagine the Theory of Total Expectation plays some sort of role, but I'm not sure how.

I would greatly appreciate any help understanding this problem, thanks.

Comment: I am confused by the adjective "randomly(uniformly)". Does it mean P(0)=P(1)=...=P(2N)? Or mean for each sock, the chance to be taken is 1/2?

Comment: Yes, it means that the probability of any sock being taken is the equal. I'll edit the question to make that more clear, sorry about that

Comment: $E(2,0)$ is correct.  To see it:  note that there are three ways we might have chosen no pairs but they are not equally probable.  We might have removed $0$ socks (a probability $\frac 14$ event).  Or we might have removed $1$ sock (also $\frac 14$).  Or we might have removed two BUT in that case we need to have chosen a mismatched pair.  That has probability $\frac 14\times \frac 23=\frac 16$.  Using these probabilities you can confirm the number.

Comment: Should say:  that calculation should provide a road map for the general one, though the result you get this way may not be pleasant.  Better methods may exist, but this is still worth doing because it will at least provide a lot of examples you can test against.

Comment: Also should say:  the problem is poorly phrased and is therefore ambiguous.  I am reading it as saying "a number $M\in \{0, 1, \cdots, 2N\}$ is selected uniformly at random and then $M$ socks removed, with every choice of $M$ socks being equally probable."  As I said, that interpretation gives the official answer for $E(2,0)$ (and for $E(2,1)$).  The way you wrote it however suggests that you meant "a probability $p$ is chosen, somehow, and then each sock independently has a probability $p$ of being removed.  I didn't work that one out but I expect it gives a different result.

Comment: Yes, the way you put it is a lot clearer. I will edit the question at once. I can also see now how E(2, 0) is correct, thanks!

Comment: @lulu Something I did not understand about your explanation, is in E(2, 0) why would the probability be $\frac{1}{4}$ for 0 socks and for 1 sock? Shouldn't it be $\frac{1}{5}$ if we consider all the values of M, or $\frac{1}{3}$ if we consider only the values of M that are possible given $K=0$ ? Sorry if the answer here is very simple, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the numbers

Comment: Sorry, not sure what I was thinking.  I certainly wrote that poorly.  The goal is to get the scaled probabilities, so that fraction almost doesn't matter.  The point is that the probability that you drew $2$ is $\frac 23$ of the probability that you drew $0$ or $1$...the fraction then disappears in the scaling.  To be precise:  not knowing how many pairs were drawn there is a $\frac 15$ chance of drawing $\{0, \cdots, 4\}$.  Now, not all those $5$ cases are equally likely to result in $0$ pairs.  For instance, you can't have drawn $3$ or $4$ socks so....

Comment: ....let's go through each case.  You might have drawn $0$ in which case you are sure to see $0$ pairs, $\frac 15$.  You might have drawn $1$ in which case you are also sure to have seen $0$ pairs, $\frac 15$ again.  You might have drawn $2$ in which case you need to have chosen one from each pair, so $\frac 15\times \frac 23$. If you chose $3$ or $4$ then you can't have seen $0$ pairs, so $0$ for both.  Thus the total probability that you saw $0$ pairs is $\frac 15+\frac 15+\frac 15\times \frac 23=\frac 8{15}$.  That's your denominator for Bayes' Theorem....

Comment: ...Thus, when you scale, the a posteriori probability that you drew $0$ or $1$ is the ratio $\left(\frac 15\right)\big/ \left(\frac 8{15}\right)=\frac 38$ and for $2$ it is $\frac 28$.   Thus the expected value $E[(2,0)=\frac 38\times 4+\frac 38\times 3+\frac 28\times 2=3.125$ as desired.  Hope that clears things up.

Comment: This clears things up quite a bit, yes! Thank you very much.
The one doubt that would remain, is how (without manually seeing what cases are possible) would one calculate the proportion of picking K pairs given M? For the case of K=0 N=2, it's pretty clear that there are 6 ways of picking 2 socks $n \choose 2$ and that two of those are pairs ($K$). But when we go to higher numbers of K and N, how could this be generalized? Intuitively, it doesn't seem to me like it would always be $\binom{n}{m}  - K$

Comment: All selections are equally likely.  To choose exactly $k$ pairs, select the pairs (so $\binom Nk$, then select which pairs of unmatched socks you'll draw from, $\binom {N-k}{m-2k}$ then pick which sock, Left or Right, you'll take from each of those, $2^{m-2k}$.  Multiply and divide by the total number of selections, $\binom {2n}m$.

Comment: Should stress: There may well be a better way to get to the final answer.  Linearity of expectation and a clever choice of indicator variables might make for a simple path.  But at least the method I sketched should be easy to program and will generate lots of examples.

Comment: I've been working on it and that cleared basically everything up! If this were an answer instead of a comment I'd accept it. Thank you very much once more